# WaitGroup is not respected in double for

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, asynchronous

I am following different examples [tutorial](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups) I have a problem nesting two loops.

**What I want**

The **sum** variable would have to give 2500

**The result**

sum = 2298, 2266, 2254

it's like the loop doesn't give you time to end

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var iterate = 50
var sum = 0

func main() {

    timeStart := time.Now()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < iterate; i++ {

        for i2 := 0; i2 < iterate; i2++ {

            wg.Add(1)

            go func() {

                defer wg.Done()

                sum++

                time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)

            }()

        }

    }

    wg.Wait()

    timeEnd := time.Now().Sub(timeStart)

    fmt.Println(timeEnd, sum)

}
```

Comment: The WaitGroups work just fine. Have you tried using the race detector?

Comment: There is an obvious race on your variable `sum`...

Comment: yes yes I didn't know this command "WARNING: DATA RACE" is it a double write attempt problem?

Comment: Its because you have multiple goroutines writing to the same variable with no locking. (And specifically has the classic race condition of "read, add one, write.") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example

Comment: the correct path is sync.RWMutex {} ?

Comment: It depends heavily on what problem you're trying to solve. You would never solve this particular problem with concurrency, so it's hard to judge what the replacement would be.

Comment: See Rob Pike's excellent discussions of this, along with various concurrency patterns in Go: https://blog.golang.org/waza-talk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments. `sum` should be protected with a `sync.Mutex`, locking before changing `sum` and unlocking after. The amended code as shown below will print out 2500.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var iterate = 50
var sum = 0

func main() {


    m := sync.Mutex{}

    timeStart := time.Now()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < iterate; i++ {

        for i2 := 0; i2 < iterate; i2++ {

            wg.Add(1)

            go func() {

                defer wg.Done()

                m.Lock()
                sum++
                m.Unlock()

                time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)

            }()

        }

    }

    wg.Wait()

    timeEnd := time.Now().Sub(timeStart)

    fmt.Println(timeEnd, sum)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is writing to a variable from different places at the same time.

**To view the error output**

```
go run -race app.go
```